# Why Can't Haskell Separate PosgreSQL String into Fields?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, ghc

I am new to PostgreSQL.Simple so please forgive if question is dumb.

I am going through this tutorial: [Postgresql Data Access with Haskell](https://tuttlem.github.io/2020/10/30/postgresql-data-access-with-haskell.html)

I got the first demo program to run.

Now I am taking this function:

```
retrieveClient :: Connection -> Int -> IO [Only String]
retrieveClient conn cid = query conn "SELECT ticker FROM spot_daily WHERE id = ?" $ (Only cid)
```

and wish to modify it to return `IO [(String, Integer, Float)]`.

So I wrote:

```
retrieveClient2 :: Connection -> Float -> IO [(String, Integer, Float)]
retrieveClient2 conn cid =  query conn "SELECT (ticker, timestamp, some_val) FROM spot_daily WHERE p_open > ?" $ (Only cid)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect localPG
  mapM_ print =<< (retrieveClient2 conn 50.0)
```

and I get this:

```
MyApp-exe.EXE: Incompatible {errSQLType = "record", errSQLTableOid = Nothing, errSQLField = "row", errHaskellType = "Text", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
```

It's common in the Haskell world to say, "Search for the type signature you want on Hackage!" but it's not clear to me from the error message what type signature would make GHC happy.

Is there a conversion function for this sort of thing? I tried doing this:

```
data MyStruct = { field1 :: String, field2 :: Integer, field3 :: Float} deriving (Eq, Show)

retrieveClient3 :: Connection -> Int -> IO [Only MyStruct]
retrieveClient3 conn cid = MyStruct (query conn "SELECT ticker FROM spot_daily WHERE id = ?" $ (Only cid))
```

but that results in a different error.

In response to a comment, here is schema for spot_daily:

```
                                     Table "public.spot_daily"
  Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default
-----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id        | integer               |           | not null | nextval('spot_daily_id_seq'::regclass)
 ticker    | character varying(20) |           | not null |
 epoch     | bigint                |           | not null |
 p_open    | double precision      |           |          |
 p_close   | double precision      |           |          |
 p_high    | double precision      |           |          |
 p_low     | double precision      |           |          |
 synthetic | boolean               |           |          |
Indexes:
    "spot_daily_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: “but that results in a different error” – namely?

Comment: Huh, I find that error surprising. In particular, the field named (`row`) doesn't appear in your query, and the type named (`Text`) doesn't appear in your type signature. Are you telling us everything? Are you sure this is the query that's causing the problem?

Comment: which error - I left that out because including it would creep the scope of the question

Comment: @DanielWagner It's the only query in the program. I just added main under retrieveClient2 to show how it is being called.

Comment: I dunno. What you've got looks fine to me. What's your DB schema for `prices_daily`?

Comment: I don't have a formal background in databases, so here's what I know. prices_daily is a table with columns such as ticker, timestamp, open, close, etc. It's worth mentioning that the query itself seems to run fine, as evidenced by the > 10 second delay where the console isn't printing anything and then the error.

Comment: The error message says that SQL is returning a record, which makes sense, and Haskell is trying to drink text. That is odd to me because I told Haskell to drink (String, Integer, Float). Is there an additional place in Haskell where I need to inform the compiler of what I'm doing?

Comment: It still seems like you're not really telling us everything (or at least, not accurately): there's no `timestamp` or `some_val` columns in the `spot_daily` table, but they're mentioned in your query. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL types make a distinction between a "row" and a "record". As written (with parentheses), your SQL query is returning a record, which isn't handled by the `FromRow` instance for tuples.

```sql
SELECT (ticker, timestamp, some_val) FROM prices_daily WHERE p_open > ?
```

Changing the query (by removing the parentheses), makes it return a row, which `postgresql-simple` should be able to handle:

```sql
SELECT ticker, timestamp, some_val FROM prices_daily WHERE p_open > ?
```

Comment: Got this: ```Incompatible {errSQLType = "record", errSQLTableOid = Nothing, errSQLField = "row", errHaskellType = "Text", errMessage = "types incompatible"}``` Error message is the same.

Comment: In that case, I agree with Daniel's comment above, it'd be helpful to see a database schema. Are you able to run queries with `psql`? If so, what does `\d prices_daily` print?

Comment: Yes. Added ```\d prices_daily``` results to question. Note that I changed prices_daily to spot_daily

Comment: It looks like neither `timestamp` or `some_val` are columns in `spot_daily`, so I'd expect your query to fail with a "column does not exist" error

Comment: I changed those names. SQL matches column names.